# Koa API server - Wait until previous request is processed before processing a new request

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, async-await, koa

I'm building an API in Node with Koa which uses another API to process some information. A request comes in to my API from the client and my API does some different requests to another API. Problem is, the other API is fragile and slow so to guarantee data integrity, I have to check if there is no previous incoming request being processed, before starting a new process. My first idea was to use promises and a global boolean to check if theres an ongoing processing and await until the process has finished. Somehow this prevents concurrent requests but even if 3-4 requests come in during the process, only the first one is done and that is it. Why are the rest of the incoming requests forgotten ?

Edit: As a side note, I do not need to respond to the incoming request with processed information. I could send response right after the request is recieved. I need to do operations with the 3rd party API.

My solution so far:
The entry point:

```
  router.get('/update', (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.body = 'Updating...';
    update();
    next();
  });
```

And the update function:

```
let updateInProgress = false;

const update = async () => {
  const updateProcess = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!updateInProgress) {
        return resolve();
      } else {
        setTimeout(updateProcess, 5000);
      }
    });
  };
  await updateProcess();
  updateInProgress = true;
  // Process the request
  updateInProgress = false
}
```

Comment: General solution to this would be a "mutex" implemented with promises which you can find on NPM. The API is something like, in your request handler: `await mutex.lock(); /* do stuff */; mutex.unlock()` such that request handlers await until prev handlers unlock.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a working solution, not sure how elegant it is tough...
I'm guessing the problem was, that new Promise was created with the Timeout function, and another one, and another one until one of them was resolved. That did not resolve the first Promise tough and the code got stuck. The solution was to create an interval which checked if the condition is met and then resolve the Promise. If someone smarter could comment, I'd appreciate it.

```
let updateInProgress = false;

const update = async () => {
  const updateProcess = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!updateInProgress) {
        return resolve();
      } else {
        const processCheck = setInterval(() => {
          if (!updateInProgress) {
            clearInterval(processCheck);
            return resolve();
          }
        }, 5000);
      }
    });
  };
  await updateProcess();
  updateInProgress = true;
  // Process the request
  updateInProgress = false
}
```